# What's does a bash function return when there is no “return” statement?

Tags: bash, shell, return-value

Is the return value of a bash function the status of the last executed command?

I wrote this test and it looks like it's so. I just want to verify. No one has asked this question before apparently and tutorials don't mention this.

Test program:

```
funa() {
  echo "in funa";
  true;
};

funb() {
  echo "in funb"
  false;
};

funa && echo "funa is true";    
funb && echo "funb is true";
```

Output when I run the program:

```
in funa
funa is true
in funb
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Per `man bash`:

> Shell Function Definitions
>
> When executed, the exit status of
>                 a function is the exit status of the last  command  executed  in
>                 the body.  (See FUNCTIONS below.)

Answer (score 4):

Did you try reading the manpage?  It's in there.

> When executed, the exit status of
>                 a  function  is  the exit status of the last command executed in
>                 the body.  (See FUNCTIONS below.)